# What does "=>" do in .Net C# when declaring a property?

Tags: c#, .net

I've seen this kind of property declaration in a .NET 4.6.1 C# project

```
public object MyObject => new object();
```

I'm used to declaring read only properties like this:

```
public object MyObject { get; }
```

I understand that there are some differences between the two (the first one creates a new object), but I would like a deeper explanation as well as some indications of when to use either of them.

Comment: added to your question. Is this also the same as the one in LINQ because I am curious too. the `Where(t => t.Whatever)`

Comment: @Aizen: No, it's not the same.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The first uses the new-to-C#-6 *expression-bodied member* syntax. It's equivalent to:

```
public object MyObject
{
    get { return new object(); }
}
```

The second is *also* new to C# 6 - an automatically implemented read-only property. It's equivalent to:

```
private readonly object _myObject; // Except using an unspeakable name
public object MyObject
{
    get { return _myObject; }
}
```

You can only assign to `MyObject` from within a constructor in the declaring class, which actually just assigns to the field instead.

(Both of these "equivalencies" are using old-school property declarations, where you always have `get`, `set` or both as blocks containing code.)

Comment: Its a shame the highest scoring member of SO doesn't leap to the "its a duplicate" option.

Comment: @MeirionHughes: Well, in this case this question is specifically asking about the difference between an automatically implemented read-only property and an expression-bodied member property. The duplicate does not ask about that. I can see it either way.

Comment: Should you not also reopen then? You have the reputation to do so single-handedly.

Comment: @MeirionHughes: I could: but I'm sufficiently uncertain either way as to wish to do anything single-handedly. If others want to close it as a dupe, that's fine by me. If others want to reopen it, that's fine by me.

Answer (score 3):

C# 6 evaluates the expression on the right of the arrow function every time you call the property getter.

In your case, you'd instantiate a `new object()` every time.

In the other case, it would read from the backing field of the property.