# How to expand this lambda function

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure how to expand this lambda function into a regular block of code, but can't seem to get it right.

```
public static IntPtr GetCurrentProcess() => new IntPtr(-1);
```

Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Comment: What does "expand" mean here?

Comment: Essentially expanding it to a regular block of code, with a return statement and all

Comment: The arrow (`=>`) syntax simply lets you avoid the curly braces and the return keyword.  So...   `IntPtr GetCurrentProcess { return new IntPtr(-1); }`   No offense, but not sure why this is confusing.

Comment: it should be a refactor option available in your IDE.. unless you are using notepad. Just context click and look for refactor options

Comment: This is inline function. What's the point?

Comment: This isn't a lambda btw, it's an "expression bodied member"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does "=>" do in .Net C# when declaring a property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35482407/what-does-do-in-net-c-sharp-when-declaring-a-property)

Comment: I goofed. I realized t hat I used regular parenthesis instead of brackets, hence I was getting errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static IntPtr GetCurrentProcess() 
{
  return new IntPtr(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Per what CodeReaper said in the comments, you can get Visual Studio to toggle between block body and expression body:

[image]

Click on the method name to put the caret in it, then open the light bulb menu in the margin. Sometimes the lightbulb is a wrench instead. You can also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to pop this menu, and it has a lot of useful stuff in different contexts, such as writing `string s` as a new parameter to your constructor and then doing "Add and init field" to add a class level field and a setter for it in the constructor body; worth looking into all the things it can do